# How to hide lines behind the surface?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw

I'm trying to draw some smooth looking surfaces with gridlines, and I'd like the grid lines to be invisible (or transparent or whatever) when they are obscured by my surface. In my code below, you'll see that I manually added the gridlines, because otherwise they seemed to become piece-wise linear.

[image: surface]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=80]
  \addplot3[surf, domain=-3:3, shader=interp] {0.1*(x^3-y^3)};
  \foreach \xx in {-3,-2.8,...,3}
  {
    \addplot3+[domain=-3:3, line width=0.05mm, mark=none, color=black, solid, samples y=0]
     ({\xx}, {x}, {0.1*\xx*\xx*\xx-0.1*x^3});
  }

  \foreach \yy in {-3,-2.8,...,3}
  {
     \addplot3[domain=-3:3, line width=0.05mm, mark=none, solid, color=black, samples y=0]
     ({x}, {\yy}, {0.1*x^3-0.1*\yy*\yy*\yy});
  }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I hide the lines behind the surface in a "smart way"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How about adding `mesh` and decreasing the samples? Like `\addplot3[samples=30,surf, domain=-3:3,mesh/ordering=y varies] {0.1*(x^3-y^3)};` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd just do

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot3[samples=30,surf,shader=faceted interp, domain=-3:3,mesh/ordering=y varies] {0.1*(x^3-y^3)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether or no you use `shader=faceted interp` is not too essential here. You'd need to use spy glasses to notice a difference.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, size=2cm, connect spies,
    every spy on node/.append style={thin}}]
  \begin{axis}[colormap/viridis,width=0.45\linewidth,title=\texttt{shader=faceted}]
  \addplot3[samples=30,surf,shader=faceted,domain=-3:3,mesh/ordering=y varies] {0.1*(x^3-y^3)};
  \end{axis}
  \spy [red,magnification=5] on (3.1,1.8) in node (zoom) [below] at (4.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}~
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, size=2cm, connect spies,
    every spy on node/.append style={thin}}]
  \begin{axis}[colormap/viridis,width=0.45\linewidth,title=\texttt{shader=faceted interp}]
  \addplot3[samples=30,surf,shader=faceted interp,domain=-3:3,mesh/ordering=y varies] {0.1*(x^3-y^3)};
  \end{axis}
  \spy [red,magnification=5] on (3.1,1.8) in node (zoom) [below] at (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If you look very closely, you'll note that the tiles on the right have some gradient shading whereas the ones on the left don't.